# Leaflet Time Dimension plugin with several WMS layers

Tags: javascript, plugins, leaflet, wms

I am currently trying to use the time dimension plug-in from leaflet to show ocean currents in a time range. I have different WMS for each month, and an I am creating a viewer with a date picker to give the user the option to select a date range. 
However, I am not able to include several WMS layers at the same time dimension layer. I don't know if this is possible.

I have tried to include all wms layers separated by a comma, but it doesn't work...

```
var MohidLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(MohidWMS);

var MohidWMS = L.tileLayer.wms("http://192.168.201.1:8601/ncWMS2/wms", {
    layers: 'RB_01_2018/velocity_U:velocity_V-group,RB_02_2018/velocity_U:velocity_V-group',
    version: '1.3.0',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    styles:'default/x-Sst,default/x-Sst',
    attribution:'MOHID/Meteogalicia',
    elevation: 35,
    // crossOrigin: null,
    colorscalerange: '0.00293,0.4695'
    // crs: 'EPSG:4326'
});
```